# GStreamer force decodebin2 output type

Tags: ffmpeg, pipeline, gstreamer

I'm trying to write a program in C which replicates the pipeline:

```
gst-launch -v filesrc location="bbb.mp4" ! decodebin2 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```

DecodeBin2 has a dynamic pad and I've attached a callback to handle its creation. I am unable to link it to ffmpegcolorspace however because the pad capability is always video/quicktime. I would like it to be video/x-raw-yuv or something else which is compatible with ffmpegcolorspace.

Is this possible to force/select the output type of decodebin2?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Please do not recommend playbin. I'm trying to learn how how to make pipelines.

Comment: why you need ffmpegcolorspace ? without that pipeline works...!!

Comment: what probably happens is decodebin2 actually already handles the colorspace conversion. So it's probably not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Is this possible to force/select the output type of decodebin2?
```

**No you can not force or select the type of its source pad.**

decoderbin2 select appropriate demuxer element and that demuxer element parse that media file and depending upon the codec of elementry stream in that media file it creates the caps/type of the output/Source pad.so that type of decoder can link with it and pipeline works.

this all happen in gstremer-plugin code

so if you want such then you need to write plugin by your self..!!

Comment: Yep, good answer - its a decoder not really a type converter. Thanks.